# JSON.parse array nested element not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am getting this error message:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or ']' after array element at line 4 column 18 of the JSON data.

I think it is because I have an object within an array, and maybe that is not allowed. But I need confirmation of this from experienced developers. Can you put objects in arrays in json?

**HTML**

```
<div id="ex1"><h2>Example 1</h2><p></p><h4>results:</h4></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var message;

  (function loadAjax()
    { var request;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
     else{

         request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft,XMLHTTP');
     }

     request.open('GET','human.json');

     request.onreadystatechange = function()
     {
         if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
             {

                 message = request.responseText;
                 var obj = JSON.parse(message);
                 var text = obj.job[0].hospital;
                 attach('ex1',text,'p');
             }
     }

     request.send();

    })();
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "sex":{"male":{"fname":["Michael","Tom"]} ,"female":{"fname":["Alice","Katie"]}},
  "age":[16,80],
  "job":["medical":{"hospital": "doctor"}, "education":{"school":"teacher"} ]
}
```

Comment: Your `job` property contains invalid assotiative-like array with object-like keys such as `medical` and `education`. An example of a valid array is the property with the `age` key. The `job` property should probably contain an object instead of array.

Comment: You just posted this elsewhere. Why not keep them in the same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37017756/json-parse-expected-or-after-property-value-in-object/37017795#37017795

Comment: @Wes Foster, this is actually different question concerning an array that I have in json. But, I didn't know you can continue to add on to a previous question that you have made

Comment: This isn't valid JSON. Are you building it manually?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter Yes, I am. Is there a better way to build it?

Comment: @MaratTanalin so you cannot create an array like that is JSON, but you can do that in regular objects... correct?

Comment: Correct. Please see my answer for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
"job":["medical":{"hospital": "doctor"}, "education":{"school":"teacher"} ]
```

This is correct:

```
"job": {"medical": {"hospital": "doctor"}, "education": {"school": "teacher"} }
```

Notice I changed the `[]` to `{}`

Square brackets are used for arrays (many individual items). Example:

```
{ "my_array": [1, 2, "three"] }      <-- Notice that the items in square brackets
                                         so not assign a value such as "key": "value"
```

Curlies are used for associative entries (many `"key": "value"` items). Example:

```
{ "my_association": { "dogs": "rule", "cats": "drool" } }
```

Please refer to [JSON.org](http://www.json.org) to learn more about the proper syntax for JSON.

Comment: Quick question, are you allowed to do the array that I had in objects or is it bad syntax in JSON and javascript objects?

Comment: Both are technically the same, they are a `Hash`. The big different is that with associative entries, you are assigning a name to the key. With normal arrays (in square brackets), you are not assigning a name to the key.

Comment: `"job":[{"medical":{"hospital":"doctor"}},{"education":{"school":"teacher"}}]`

is what the op was originally after, but he simply forgot to wrap them  key-value pairs in {}.

Answer (score 0):

Your `job` property contains an invalid associative-like array with object-like keys such as `medical` and `education`. An example of a valid array is the property with the `age` key. The `job` property should probably contain an object instead of array.

JavaScript array is just a list of values (`["foo", "bar"]`) without explicit keys. If you need a `key:value` pairs, use an object (`{"a" : "foo", "b" : "bar"}`).

By the way, it generally makes sense to generate JSON automatically (not manually), e. g. using PHP’s built-in function [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), so that the resulting JSON code is guaranteedly valid.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to correct your:

```
{
  "sex":{"male":{"fname":["Michael","Tom"]} ,"female":{"fname":["Alice","Katie"]}},
  "age":[16,80],
  "job":["medical":{"hospital": "doctor"}, "education":{"school":"teacher"} ]
}
```

to:

```
{
  "sex":{"male":{"mname":["Michael","Tom"]},"female":{"fname":["Alice","Katie"]}},
  "age":[16,80],
  "job":[{"medical":{"hospital":"doctor"}},{"education":{"school":"teacher"}}]
}
```

in case you really want to preserve your original idea of structure & access.